# Ajax/Woocommerce - JavaScript - How to get product price having product ID

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, woocommerce

I need to run JavaScript while adding products to the basket. I have product id (in JavaScript/ajax) and I need to get price of the product (in JavaScript/ajax also).

The script uses both variables - product id and product price.

```
<script>
    (function($){
        $('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(e, fragments, cart_hash, this_button){
            var dddata = $(this_button).data('product_id');
            console.log(dddata);
        });
    })(jQuery); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
    var price = $('.post-' + dddata + ':eq(0) .amount').text();
```